# Vagrant CoreOS box missing fleetctl

Tags: vagrant, coreos, fleetctl

I am following the CoreOS in Action book (and also [CoreOS online instruction](https://coreos.com/blog/coreos-clustering-with-vagrant.html)) to bring up a 3-node cluster using Vagrant and VirtualBox on MacOS.

It all goes fine, machines come up & running and I can ssh into one of them, but it looks like the boxes brought up are missing `fleetctl` (which makes no sense, as it's such a core component of CoreOS):

```
$ vagrant ssh core-01 -- -A
Last login: Thu Mar  1 21:28:58 UTC 2018 from 10.0.2.2 on pts/0
Container Linux by CoreOS alpha (1702.0.0)
core@core-01 ~ $ fleetctl list-machines
-bash: fleetctl: command not found
core@core-01 ~ $ which fleetctl
which: no fleetctl in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have changed the number of instances to 3, created a new "discovery token URL" and updated the `user.data` file; Googling around I seem to be the one and only person having this problem.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have!

PS -- yes, I have tried (several times!) to `vagrant destroy` and rebuild the cluster: even nuked the repo and re-cloned it.  Same issue every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is going to make you a bit sad, here it is:

CoreOS no longer support fleet. It's gone. Ciao :(

https://coreos.com/blog/migrating-from-fleet-to-kubernetes.html

> To this end, CoreOS will remove fleet from Container Linux on February 1, 2018, and support for fleet will end at that time. fleet has already been in maintenance mode for some time, receiving only security and bugfix updates, and this move reflects our focus on Kubernetes and Tectonic for cluster orchestration and management.

You are using Coreos **1702.0.0**, fleet has been removed since Coreos **1675.0.1** https://coreos.com/releases/

Comment: Oh, and remember that CoreOS got acquired by red hat a few weeks ago, so stay tuned for some potentially major changes while you are learning CoreOS

Comment: well, it actually doesn't make **me** sad, but sure all the folks who have written books on CoreOS will be ;-) (I was following along with CoreOS in Action and figured that there was no point going forward, if I couldn't get past page 10...).  Many thanks for answer, appreciated!

Yes, I saw the RH news and also makes me wonder whether I want to continue down the CoreOS path: will they do them what ORCL did to MySQL?

Comment: Do you have a copy of that blog post? RH removed that page =(

Comment: @EugenKonkov wayback machine has a copy. http://web.archive.org/web/20181206115701/https://coreos.com/blog/migrating-from-fleet-to-kubernetes.html